# Why does array "each" do not work anymore in Crystal 1.3.0? What should I use instead?

Tags: crystal-lang

The code below does not print the elements of the array. Why is that?

```
array = [1, 2, 3]

array.each do |x|
  puts x
end

array.each { |x| puts x }
```

[Crystal Play Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAMgd.png)

It used to work in previous versions. I know Crystal is not Ruby, but the code above works in Ruby. What is the best practice to iterate through an array in Crystal? And why did the Crystal developers decide to make Crystal incompatible with Ruby in such a basic scenario?

Comment: Include versions used in your questions, especially when you claim it worked in previous versions. What version are you using now? What version did it work in?

Comment: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/clh9 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: click "SHOW OUTPUT" below right-hand side box.

There is an apparent difference between the local version of Crystal Playground you get from running `crystal play` and the one running at play.crystal-lang.org. The code works, but the presentation of the results is different.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the output was being shown by default. Never occurred to me that I had to click there.

Answer (score -3):

The crystal playground cannot execute this code for some reason.

Don't use the crystal playground. It is currently close to useless.

Put the code in a file and do:

`crystal each.cr`

And you will see the array elements.

Comment: Seems to work for me. https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/clh7

Comment: Try `crystal play` on your machine and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`. Run the code to see that it does not work.

Comment: Yes, `crystal play` and https://play.crystal-lang.org are entirely different things. The naming overload is very unfortunate and might cause this confusion.

I disagree with that `crystal play` would be useless. It works pretty well. Maybe not the way you expect it to.
That is, for the most part at least. There are some edge cases and differences to normal compiler behaviour which I think make it unsuitable for newcomers trying to understand the language. Despite that being one of its main purposes.
It's not useless, but you need to be aware how it works in order to use it properly.